# Assign a value based on time and specific day (2 different variables)

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

I am trying to assign a specific working shift letter to a new column based on the time and day of the record in my sheet.

I created 2 new fields to make the calculation easier.

- Using my "date" column ("m/dd/yyyy"), I created a column called "WeekDay" that basically displays the day of every record with a number from 1 to 7
  (1 = Monday 5=Friday, etc).
- Using my "time" column ("hh:mm AM/PM"), I created a column called "Hour of Day" that displays a number from 0 to 24 based on the time
  of my record (i.e:5:40 AM = 5)

The working shifts letters I want to use are as followed:

- A shift - Mon to Fri from 6 to 14 hrs.
- B shift - Mon to Fri from 14 to 22 hrs.
- C shift - Mon to Fri from 22 to 6 hrs.
- WD (Weekend Day) Shift - Sat and Sun from 6 to 18 hrs.
- WN (Weekend Night) Shift -Sat and Sun from 18 to 6 hrs.

Below is what I have done, the code works but only for Shifts A, B and C. I cannot make it work, so, it also includes WD and WN.

```
=IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=6,[@[Hour of Day]]<14,OR([@WeekDay]=1,[@WeekDay]=2,[@WeekDay]=3,[@WeekDay]=4,[@WeekDay]=5)),"A",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]<22,[@[Hour of Day]]>=14,OR([@WeekDay]=1,[@WeekDay]=2,[@WeekDay]=3,[@WeekDay]=4,[@WeekDay]=5)),"B",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=22,[@[Hour of Day]]<6,OR([@WeekDay]=1,[@WeekDay]=2,[@WeekDay]=3,[@WeekDay]=4,[@WeekDay]=5)),"C",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=6,[@[Hour of Day]]<18,OR([@WeekDay]=6,[@WeekDay]=7)),"WD",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>18,[@[Hour of Day]]>0,[@[Hour of Day]]<6,OR([@WeekDay]=6,[@WeekDay]=7)),"WN","C")))))
```

Comment: Look at the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED)

Comment: Why not save half the expression by using something similar to `AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=6,[@[Hour of Day]]<14,@[Weekday]<=5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last IF condition is faulty. You have Hour > 18 and Hour < 6 which is never going to be met. You need to break it into two if statements. If Day = 6 or 7 and Hour > 18, then WN, else if Day = 7 or 1 and Hour < 6, then

```
=IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=6,[@[Hour of Day]]<14,OR([@Weekday]=1,[@Weekday]=2,[@Weekday]=3,[@Weekday]=4,[@Weekday]=5)),"A",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]<22,[@[Hour of Day]]>=14,OR([@Weekday]=1,[@Weekday]=2,[@Weekday]=3,[@Weekday]=4,[@Weekday]=5)),"B",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=22,[@[Hour of Day]]<6,OR([@Weekday]=1,[@Weekday]=2,[@Weekday]=3,[@Weekday]=4,[@Weekday]=5)),"C",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=6,[@[Hour of Day]]<18,OR([@Weekday]=6,[@Weekday]=7)),"WD",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]>=18,OR([@Weekday]=6,[@Weekday]=7)),"WN",
IF(AND([@[Hour of Day]]<6,OR([@Weekday]=1,[@Weekday]=7)),"WN","C"))))))
```

UPDATE

Taking into account the flaws in your original formula pointed out by @Jaquez, I worked out this formula.

```
=IF((FLOOR((([@Weekday]*24+[@[Hour of Day]]-6)+7*24)/24,1))<6,CHOOSE(ROUNDUP([@[Hour of Day]]/8,0),"A","B","C"),IF((MOD([@S2],24))<12,"WD","WN"))
```

I am calculating the duration in hours from the start of the week and offsetting it by 6 to eliminate overlap of C shift across days. Then I am using mode to split the shifts to 8 hour shifts during weekdays and 12 hour shifts during weekends.

Doing this in a hurry and so let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Now THAT is some outside the box thinking.  Much more straightforward logically, even if conceptually it might be harder to work out what is going on later.

Comment: This looks really cool. It is a little bit more complex than the previous nested if, but it works great! I will try to really understand how it works and may ask you for some clarification in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like @eshwar mentioned, the main problem is that `AND(Hour>=22,Hour<6)` will never be true.  Change that to `OR(Hour<6,Hour>=22)` and you're mostly there.  But if you follow along below, you can remove it altogether to eliminate the confusion.

First, rather that repeating yourself, I would pull the day of the week out into a parent `IF` to simplify the logic.  And rather than checking the weekday against every single possible value, just check if `Weekday<=5` and you have save yourself even more.

This also makes `Weekday>=6` a given in the `[value_if_false]` part of the parent `IF` since anything that makes it there is already a weekend and you can just check the if the time is `AND(Hour>=6,Hour<18)` for `"WD"`.

This leaves the same original problem for `"WN"`, namely `OR(Hour<6,Hour>=18)` instead of `AND`, but since this is, again, the only remaining option, you can omit that as well and just make `"WN"` the `[value_if_false]` part.

I've used indenting to show nesting:

```
=IF(WeekDay<=5,
    IF(AND(Hour_of_Day>=6,Hour_of_Day<14),"A",
       IF(AND(Hour_of_Day>=14,Hour_of_Day<22),"B","C")),
    IF(AND(Hour_of_Day>=6,Hour_of_Day<18),"WD","WN"))
```

Which produces this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
1   C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
2   C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
3   C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
4   C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
5   C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
6   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
7   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
8   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
9   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
10  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
11  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
12  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
13  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
14  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
15  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
16  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
17  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
18  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
19  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
20  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
21  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
22  C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
23  C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
```

Hopefully this the formatting and brevity make it easier to understand, decreasing the chances of logic errors.

**Update:** Darn inability to let it go!

This covers the instance where Shift C works Friday nights in to Saturday and Shift WN works Sunday nights into Monday:

```
=IF(WeekDay<=5,
    IF(AND(Hour_of_Day>=6,Hour_of_Day<14),"A",
       IF(AND(Hour_of_Day>=14,Hour_of_Day<22),"B",
          IF(AND(WeekDay=1,Hour_of_Day<6),"WN","C"))),
    IF(AND(Hour_of_Day>=6,Hour_of_Day<18),"WD",
       IF(AND(WeekDay=6,Hour_of_Day<6),"C","WN")))
```

Which produces this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   WN  C   C   C   C   C   WN
1   WN  C   C   C   C   C   WN
2   WN  C   C   C   C   C   WN
3   WN  C   C   C   C   C   WN
4   WN  C   C   C   C   C   WN
5   WN  C   C   C   C   C   WN
6   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
7   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
8   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
9   A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
10  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
11  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
12  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
13  A   A   A   A   A   WD  WD
14  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
15  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
16  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
17  B   B   B   B   B   WD  WD
18  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
19  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
20  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
21  B   B   B   B   B   WN  WN
22  C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
23  C   C   C   C   C   WN  WN
```

Comment: Good catch! I did not realize that "WN" was the catchall as there was a "C" at the end. This is simpler and better but there is one problem with this. When weekday = 1 and hour < 6, this will result in C but it should be "WN".

Comment: Indeed, I did notice that just before submitting but I'm not entirely sure the OP's code wouldn't have done the same and, logic and experience aside, I just went with it.  The same problem appears on Friday nights before midnight as well.  That certainly complicates the logic again, though.  I'll try to get back to it and fix it.

Comment: Now it's fixed.  It wasn't as bad as I expected, I guess since everything else was already simplified.

Comment: Jaquez and @eshwar, this makes way more sense! Thanks a lot for the help! I think I understood what you just explained, I will dive into it!

Comment: So, after I run the formula it will compute all values Tue-Thu correctly but WD, WN, Fridays A. Fridays "A" shift will have WD instead of A, and Mondays < 6 has C instead of WN. Any insights?

Comment: @Josh I've updated the answer to show what each of my formulas produces.  If neither of these are what you are looking for, can you let me know in a similar manner what you need?

Comment: @Jaquez, The result of you second formula is what I am looking for. Your formula works perfect! I apologize for my mistake, the way I had the format of my cell was wrong. I had Sunday being 1 rather than 7. I fixed it and everything looks great! You are genius man! Thanks a lot!